# Reportbuilder (digital-metaphors) Sum with comma values is not functioning..need Directions?

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I am working with firebird 2,5 and Delphi XE and Reportbuilder.
I have a table with a column containing values like 12,15 and 52,63 now in summary band of report i use DBCALC and want to have Total Sum of this column. 
The Problem is the result is not correct it comes up 64 instead of 64,78
How can i resolve this problem ? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the box in your total line is wide enough to display the complete number. The default might make it a little too small.